# OpenCV trackbar crashes process when moved

Tags: python, macos, numpy, opencv

The code could be running, and the window could show up successfully, but when I wanted to move the value on tackbar, the window would be closed immediately, and terminal only showed `zsh: segmentation fault`!

OS: MacBookPro13_macOS Ventura (13.0.0)
Device: IntelCorei7-1068NG7 2.30GHz
running on VScode(version:3.9.6)
cv2_version: 4.6.0
sys_version: 3.9.6
numpy_version: 1.23.4

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

def empty(x):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('hsv_demo')
h, s, v = 100, 100, 100

cv2.createTrackbar('hl', 'hsv_demo', 0,   179, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('hu', 'hsv_demo', 179, 179, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('sl', 'hsv_demo', 0,   255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('su', 'hsv_demo', 255, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('vl', 'hsv_demo', 0,   255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('vu', 'hsv_demo', 255, 255, empty)

try:
    imagePath = sys.argv[1]
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
except:
    image = cv2.imread("/Volumes/Program/10. data_photo/lena512rgb.png")

while True:
    hl = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hl', 'hsv_demo')
    hu = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hu', 'hsv_demo')
    sl = cv2.getTrackbarPos('sl', 'hsv_demo')
    su = cv2.getTrackbarPos('su', 'hsv_demo')
    vl = cv2.getTrackbarPos('vl', 'hsv_demo')
    vu = cv2.getTrackbarPos('vu', 'hsv_demo')

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower = np.array([hl, sl, vl])
    upper = np.array([hu, su, vu])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("hsv_demo", result)
    print(hl, hu, sl, su, vl, vu)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        cv2.imwrite("hsv_demo.png", result)
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The print kept showing `0 179 0 255 0 255` until I moving the value, terminal showed `zsh: segmentation fault`

The same code on raspberry Pi4 is no problem

[image]

Comment: Is that the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce it? Likely not, so please keep whittling it down to the absolute minimum. Then, it would be a good idea to post a bug report on [OpenCV's github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues).

Comment: I had tried it, and result as you said. Thanx for your opinion, I will try to post on OpenCV's github.